# Build failed: could not resolve com.takisoft.fix:preference-v7:25.3.0.0

Tags: java, android, gradle, build, dependencies

very new to coding. I successfully built, tested, and uploaded my very simple Android App to Google Play. But since building version 2 and trying to generate the APK, I'm running into this Build Gradle and ReleaseSigningConfig issue:

### :app:writeReleaseSigningConfigVersions:
1: Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:dataBindingMergeDependencyArtifactsRelease'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:releaseCompileClasspath'.
> Could not find com.takisoft.fix:preference-v7:25.3.0.0.
> Required by:
> project :app

**Note takisoft is already in build.grade (:app)...How come it can't be found?**

Any advice would be SUPER appreciated, I've tried everything I could find online. Including:

- Checking gradle offline mode
- Updating Grade Plugins and other dependencies
- Invalidate Cache/Restart and Syncing Gradle (painfully this also deleted Local History)

**AndroidManifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:versionCode="2"
    android:versionName="1.1"
    android:compileSdkVersion="32"
    android:compileSdkVersionCodename="12"
    package="com.AppName">


    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

    <application
        android:name=".AppName"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/blue_paw_icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@drawable/blue_paw_icon"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppName">
        <activity
            android:name=".SettingsActivity"
            android:exported="true" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="preloaded_fonts"
            android:resource="@array/preloaded_fonts" />

        <receiver
            android:name=".AlarmReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.action.DISPLAY_NOTIFICATION" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**build.gradle (:app)**

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
 }

 android {
    signingConfigs {
       release {
            storeFile file('FILE_PATH')
            storePassword '...'
            keyAlias '...'
            keyPassword '...'
        }
    }
    compileSdk 32

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.AppName"
        minSdk 16
        targetSdk 32
        versionCode 2
        versionName "1.1"
        multiDexEnabled true

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }

    signingConfigs {
        debug {
            storeFile file('FILE_PATH')
            storePassword '...'
            keyPassword '...'
            keyAlias 'AppName'
        }
        release {
            keyAlias 'AppName'
            keyPassword '...'
            storeFile file('FILE_PATH')
            storePassword '...'
        }
    }


    buildTypes {
        release {
            shrinkResources true
            minifyEnabled true
            debuggable false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release

        }
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }
 }

 dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.2.1'
    implementation 'androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.4.1'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.4.1'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.3.5'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.3.5'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.6.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'

    def nav_version = "2.4.1"

    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:$nav_version"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:$nav_version"

    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:26.2.0')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:23.0.2'

    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.takisoft.fix:preference-v7:25.3.0.0'

}
```

**build.gradle (project)**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.4'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.6.10-RC"

    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
    google()
        mavenCentral()

}}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Have you tried gradle's `refreshDependecies`?? also is [this](https://github.com/Gericop/Android-Support-Preference-V7-Fix) the library? because it should be added differently

Comment: don't you think you need to update Android Studio? You are using a very old version

Comment: @mohsensameti yes this was super helpful! Really basic mistake but I didn't realize that the '$androidxVersion' or '$nav_version' were placeholders that need to be replaced with the desired version code!! Once I updated those, everything is running well again. Thank you!!

Comment: @Sambhav.K interesting, I'll look into updating. Out of curiosity, how can you tell which version I am using?

Comment: No idea. Many versions had this. But, u can update it

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Mohsensameti realized that my build.gradle file was throwing errors because I didn't update the version code for my implementation dependencies.

For example, when the implementation ends in '$androidxVersion' or '$nav_version'...then those need to be replaced with the desired version code (e.g., 2.4.1)

Super straightforward solution that solved it immediately!!